# CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to integrate cloud firestore to an android app but all I get is this error every single time

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.